# Is there a way to upload a .csv file to Google Docs using a Google Sheets as a template?

Tags: google-sheets, csv, google-sheets-import-csv

- I am generating a .CSV file with an application.
- I then upload the .CSV file to Google Docs, which creates a Google Docs Spreadsheet which is "plain and white".
- I then have to manually format the .CSV file with colors and bold-headers, etc.

Is there a way for me to create a Google Sheets and then say "upload this CSV file and use this spreadsheet as a template"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [importData("URL")](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507) function to achieve your goal.

1. Upload the CSV file somewhere that you can have public access to (I suggest [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) or [Ge.tt](http://ge.tt)) and you'll endup with something like `http://example.com/foo.csv`
2. Go the the first cell that you want to insert your data and write: `=importData("http://example.com/foo.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Copy your template over the plain vanilla with Paste special, Paste format only.